# Htaccess rewrite url for images - page title + image url

Tags: image, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I saw some subjects but not like mine.

So I want to rewrite url for all images using htaccess.

The exact image url may be www.site.com/attachments/12345.jpg ( www.site.com/attachments/**number**.jpg )

I want to show them (in source) like www.site.com/this-is-the-article-title/this-is-the-article-title-12345.jpg

Comment: Where does the article title come from?  And what do you mean by "in source"?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't matter where the title is coming from. I just want to rewrite the url as mentioned. I mean source, because I want to rewrite the url, so in the source will be www.site.com/this-is-the-article-title/this-is-the-article-title-12345.jpg, but in reality, the image location is www.site.com/attachments/12345.jpg.

Comment: Do you mean that the url someone types in is `www.site.com/this-is-the-article-title/this-is-the-article-title-12345.jpg`?  "Source", to me, says "html source code".  Or possibly "actual location on the computer", but that seems to be a better description of "the real image location".